# Aplicação executa normalmente no Tomcat embarcado do Spring Boot e não executa no Tomcat do meu Servidor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

boa tarde.
Estou tendo um problema com uma aplicação usando o Spring Boot 2.
Basicamente é um RestAPI com alguns métodos "schedulados".

No Tomcat embarcado do Spring Boot ela funciona normalmente, executa os métodos schedulados e responde as requisições HTTP.

Fiz o Deploy do "war" no meu servidor Tomcat de produção, o status da aplicação fica como "Executando", porém quando faço uma requisição HTTP o contexto não é encontrado e recebo o erro 404. Também percebi que no servidor embarcado do Spring Boot os logs que coloquei utilizando a classe LOGGER para que pudesse acompanhar quando um método schedulado fosse executado são exibidos normalmente, já no meu Tomcat de produção esses logs não aparecem.

Alguém se deparou com algo parecido?

Abaixo o arquivo POM da minha aplicação

insira o código aqui

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
         
    
    ###integracaoMega
    integracaoMega
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    war
    integracaoMega
    Serviço para integração entre Mega e RM

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para rodar em tomcat externo tem que fazer duas coisas:

1 - Incluir a dependencia no seu pom.xml - Já esta feito no seu caso

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

2 - Alterar a application class para herdar de `SpringBootServletInitializer`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

}
```

Quando precisei rodar a minha aplicação em um tomcat externo alterei esses dois itens e tudo rodou perfeito.

Comment: rnd_rss, obrigado pelo retorno, a dependência já estava no arquivo POM, porém havia esquecido de extender a SpringBootServletInitializer.